# Sample Concurrency projects in Java

Tags: java, concurrency

I finished reading the first seven chapters of Java Concurrency in Practice. Can you give me any ideas of sample projects so that my ideas will become solidified ?

Comment: Go to [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net) and search "Java concurrency".

Answer (score 1):

How about implementing your own 'thread safe' list and then making multiple threads add, get, and remove elements from it?  Liberal use of System.out would show you just how interesting it can get when multiple threads work on the same data structure.

Answer (score 1):

This guy has a great set of tutorials on concurrency. [jenkov tutorials](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/locks.html#fairness)

One interesting exercise try to create a "fair" lock using nothing but the simplest java language constructs. It allows you to become intimately familiar with all the paranoia inducing aspects of threads(race conditions, missed signals, etc.) and helps us come to terms with why the prospect of writing multi-threaded applications keep me up at night.